# array.sort() by date string mess up,javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, date

I am stuck with a javascript sorting function `array`.sort by passing in a compare function to make the array(array of array) to be sorted by date desc.

Here is my test script :

```
var obj ={data:[["20150130"],["20150131"],["20150201"],["20150202"],["20150203"],["20140101"]]};// actually there are some values else in the inner array

console.log("before sort",obj.data);
obj.data.sort(function(o1,o2){//sort the data
    //if(o1[0]==o2[0]) return 0;
    var year1=o1[0].substring(0,4);
    var month1=o1[0].substring(4,6);
    var day1=o1[0].substring(6,8);

    var year2=o2[0].substring(0,4);
    var month2=o2[0].substring(4,6);
    var day2=o2[0].substring(6,8);

    //console.log("date1 : ",new Date(year1,month1,day1));
    //console.log("date2 : ",new Date(year2,month2,day2));
    //console.log(-(new Date(year1,month1,day1) -new Date(year2,month2,day2)));

    return -(new Date(year1,month1,day1)-new Date(year2,month2,day2));
   //return -(new Date(parseInt(year1,10), parseInt(month1,10)-1, parseInt(day1,10)) -new Date(parseInt(year2), parseInt(month2,10)-1, parseInt(day2,10)));   // is messing up too

});

console.log("after sort",obj.data);
```

Result:

```
before sort [["20150130"], ["20150131"], ["20150201"], ["20150202"], ["20150203"], ["20140101"]]

after sort [["20150203"], ["20150131"], ["20150202"], ["20150130"], ["20150201"], ["20140101"]]
```

Thank you!

---

### updated

I use

```
funtion(o1,02){
    if (o2 ==o1) return 0;
    return o1 > o2 ? -1 :1;
}
```

and it seems to work, **while I still hope to get a CLEAR ANSWER for why the original code does not work at all**. Thank you!

Comment: Your dates sort just like numbers. Why not just parse them as numbers?

Comment: Did your question get answered?  If so, please select one of the answers and mark it as the best answer by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because your date strings are YYYYMMDD (the date components are in priority order) and they are zero padded to fixed length, you don't have to parse at all or use a custom sort.  You can just sort by the strings:

```
obj.data.sort().reverse();
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/q4cddpx3/

---

In your solution, I see you are passing strings instead of numbers to the `Date()` constructor and for month values, you are passing values in the range of 1 to 12 rather than 0 to 11.  I'm not sure if anything else is wrong.

Comment: "Because your date strings are YYYYMMDD (the date components are in priority order) and they are zero padded to fixed length", would you please update your answer to demostrate how this produce my problem? I will accept your answer then. Thank you!

Comment: @Jaskey - That padding didn't cause your problem.  It's just a fact I could rely on to create a very simple way to sort.  I didn't analyze your code in detail to uncover everything wrong with it.  I do see that you're passing in strings, not numbers to the `Date()` constructor and passing the month as values from 1-12 when the `Date()` constructor expects 0-11.  I'm not sure what else might be wrong.

Comment: But even though I use `return -(new Date(parseInt(year1,10), parseInt(month1,10)-1, parseInt(day1,10)) -new Date(parseInt(year2), parseInt(month2,10)-1, parseInt(day2,10)));`   it is still messing up.

Comment: This will not work because the dates in are one-element arrays, which sort has no idea how to compare.

Comment: @torazaburo - [The EcmaSscript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.11) says that it will sort by a `toString()` conversion of the element if no callback is provided for `.sort()` so that's why this works.  `.toString()` on a single element array that contains a string is just that string.

Comment: Simple demo of the nested array sort that uses the nested array string conversion: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/dbqktkda/

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
obj.data.sort(function(o1,o2){//sort the data
    //if(o1[0]==o2[0]) return 0;
    var year1=o1[0].substring(0,4);
    var month1=o1[0].substring(4,6);
    var day1=o1[0].substring(6,8);

    var year2=o2[0].substring(0,4);
    var month2=o2[0].substring(4,6);
    var day2=o2[0].substring(6,8);

    console.log("date1 : ",new Date(year1,month1,day1));
    console.log("date2 : ",new Date(year2,month2,day2));
    console.log(-(new Date(year1,month1,day1) -new Date(year2,month2,day2)));

    Date d1 = new Date(year1,month1,day1);
    Date d2 = new Date(year2,month2,day2);
    if (d1 < d2)
        return -1;
    if (d1 == d2)
        return 0;
    return 1;
});
```

But as someone has already suggested replace strings with numbers and you can sort it like normal numbers.

Comment: This syntax is not Javascript: `Date d1 = new Date(year1,month1,day1);`  You would use `var` instead.  You should also pass numbers, not strings to the `Date()` constructor.

Comment: Why would you go to all the trouble of parsing the date yourself when the dates are already in sortable format as strings?

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```js
var obj ={data:[["20150130"],["20150131"],["20150201"],["20150202"],["20150203"],["20140101"]]};

obj.data = obj.data.sort(function(d1, d2){
   return (new Date(+d1[0])) < (new Date(+d2[0]))
});

document.write(obj.data.join(',')); // Just for test
```

Comment: What is the functional difference here between your comparison function and just `d1[0] < d2[0] ? -1 : +1`?

Answer (score 0):

You're making life unnecessarily hard for yourself. You just need to sort the array by the first and only value of each sub-array:

```
obj.data.sort(function(x, y) {
    return x[0] < y[0] ? -1 : +1;
});
```

Or, you could avoid having to define your own comparison function by unwinding the arrays, then sorting, then putting the dates back into their little one-element arrays:

```
obj . data . 
    map(function(subarray) { return subarray[0]; }) .
    sort() .
    map(function(date) { return [date]; });
```

Comment: Thank you. I realized this after @ jfriend00 's hlep, and actually I use 'funtion(o1,02){if (o2 ==o1) return 0;return o1 > o2 ? -1 :1;}' at the end, But I am curious why the original code does not work, I guess I miss something or get something wrong. So I hope to get an answer for this.